# Definition of power functions

Tags: performance, comparative-review, memory-management, lisp

I needed to write a simple function that could raise a value `x` to the `n`'th power. I found out I could write this function in 2 different ways:

```
(defun power1 (x n)
  "Raise x to the n'th power"
  (cond ((zerop n)
          1.0)
         ((< n 0.0)
          (/ 1.0 (reduce #'* (loop for i below (- n) collect x))))
         (t
          (reduce #'* (loop for i below n collect x)))))

(defun power2 (x n)
  "Raise x to the n'th power"
  (cond ((zerop n)
         1.0)
        ((< n 0.0)
         (/ 1.0 (power2 x (- n))))
        (t
         (* x (power2 x (- n 1))))))
```

Now, I was curious to known which of these 2 functions is better. So I ran some calls to these functions wrapped in a call to the `time` function. Here are some results:

> ```
> (time (power1 2 100))
> took 0 milliseconds (0.000 seconds) to run.
> 2,248 bytes of memory allocated.
>
> (time (power2 2 100))
> took 0 milliseconds (0.000 seconds) to run.
> 800 bytes of memory allocated.
>
> (time (power1 2 1000))
> took 0 milliseconds (0.000 seconds) to run.
> 82,232 bytes of memory allocated.
>
> (time (power2 2 1000))
> > Error: FLOATING-POINT-OVERFLOW detected
> ```

The first function takes more memory, since it creates an entire list, while the second function uses recursion. But the first one can handle larger numbers.

How can I choose which of these functions is the best? Choose for memory usage, readability, Lisp-like style, range of inputs it can handle, .... Maybe a function that uses tail-call optimization would be even better?

```lisp
(defun power3 (x n)
  (labels ((pow (x n acc)
             (if (zerop n)
                 acc
                 (pow x (- n 1) (* acc x)))))
    (cond ((zerop n) 1.0)
          ((< n 0.0) (/ 1.0 (pow x (- n) 1.0)))
          (t (pow x n 1.0)))))

(time (power3 2 100))
took 1 milliseconds (0.001 seconds) to run.
800 bytes of memory allocated.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Major

All 3 of your functions are *linear* (they do `O(n)` multiplications) while, in fact, only `O(log(n))` is necessary:

```
(defun pow (x n)
  (if (minusp n)
      (/ (pow x (- n)))
      (multiple-value-bind (d r) (floor n 2)
        (let ((p (if (zerop d) 1 (pow x d))))
          (* p p (if (zerop r) 1 x))))))
```

In addition to much fewer multiplications, I am returning ratios for rational `x`.

## Minor

Use [`minusp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_minusp.htm) instead of comparison with `0.0` and `(/ a)` instead of `(/ 1 a)`.

Comment: It's possible to exponentiate quicker by abusing the rules of exponentiation. Consider how you would divide exponentiation calculation up in bigger units recursively and the answer should be obvious

Comment: @Vogel612: are you suggesting an improvement to my implementation?

Comment: @sds I should've pinged the person I was talking to. I was trying to illustrate to the OP how to achieve a log(n) runtime complexity

Comment: @Vogel612: I don't think my log(n) implementation is an "abuse" of the rules.

Comment: 'Course not. It might help the OP to understand themselves though :)

Answer (score 1):

### Naming

The name `n` suggests a natural number even though that is not case in the implementation which operates over integer values. More importantly, perhaps, it does not reflect the 'problem domain' or 'business logic' of the underlying mathematics in which exponents can be anything that counts as a number.

### Precision

The use of floating point values limits the precision of the numeric results and does not take full advantage of Common Lisp's numeric system: e.g. arbitrarily large integers and exact ratios.

### Completeness

The function does not handle non-integer values for the exponent, e.g. `(pow 3 1/2)` throws an error instead of returning the square root of 3.

In fairness, Common Lisp includes a function [`expt`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_exp_e.htm#expt) that performs the operation. The [implementation in SBCL](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/master/src/code/irrat.lisp) is non-trivial at just under 200 lines of code (begins at line 158).

### Speed

Optimization applied at the [wrong time and/or in the wrong place](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) has been known to occasionaly lead programmers astray. This seems to be a case where the hard problem is writing code that reflects the underlying mathematics has been foresaken for benchmarking implementations that don't.

### Recommendations

The code might be improved by acknowledging the problem domain. For example `exponent` rather than `n`. It might be improved by testing for mathematically sound arguments that it does not handle for example:

```
  (if (integerp exponent)...
```

#### Minor Point

Because `(*) => 1`, it may not be necessary to use `(zerop exponent)`... depending on the implementation, of course.